# ListView "Sequence contains no elements" exception on build

Tags: android, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I'm building in Xamarin Studio (Mac) and I'm getting a "Sequence contains no elements" error every time i build. What could be the issue?

Xaml code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
xmlns ="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"

x:Class="AJInspector.MenuPage"
Padding="10"
BackgroundColor="Gray"
Title="Inspector Menu">


        <ContentPage.Content>

            <StackLayout Margin="5,30,5,5">
                <Label Text="AInspector Menu">
                </Label>
                <SearchBar Placeholder="search" PlaceholderColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="Center" SearchButtonPressed="Find_SearchButtonPressed" >
                </SearchBar>
                <Button Text="Inspect" BackgroundColor="Lime" Clicked="FormA_Clicked">
                </Button>
                <Button Text="+ Client Record" BackgroundColor="Silver" Clicked="AddVehicle_Clicked">
                </Button>
            </StackLayout>

            <ListView x:Name="NewVehicles">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       <ViewCell>

                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Make}" ></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding VModel}" ></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding VReg}" ></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                                    <Button Text="?" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Button>
                            </StackLayout>

                       </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Code is implemented on the master page of a masterDetail page.
ListView's itemSource is set in page class C# OnAppearing() method. 
Build is for android.

This is my first Xamarin app, Please help.

Comment: You need to put a container around your `StackLayout` and `ListView`. Your `ContentPage.Content` can only have one child.

Comment: By "Container" Do you mean like another "<ContentPage.Content></ContentPage.Content>" around the <listView>?

Comment: No, I mean, for instance another `StackLayout` around the existing `StackLayout` and `ListView`. I.e.: `<ContentPage.Content><StackLayout><StackLayout></StackLayout<ListView></ListView></StackLayout></ContentPage.Content>` In a `Page` there can be one `Content`, in a `Content` there can be one child. Within that child you can created nested layouts.

Comment: Thanks @GeraldVersluis ... That fixed it!

Comment: Updated it to an answer, please don't forget to accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `Page` there can be *one* `Content`, in the Page's `Content` there can be *one* child. Within that child you can created nested layouts. So in your example, if you would want to use a `StackLayout`, you will end up with this structure:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Although the error you describe:

> Sequence contains no elements

Seems to be about a collection in your code, the fact that it happens at compile-time tells you that it has to be something in your layout. Else the exception would happen at runtime.

The error is still about a collection, but in this case originates from the Xamarin internals putting your layout elements in some kind of collection and hitting an error because of your invalid XAML code.

If you haven't enabled it already, please consider using XAML compilation (read more [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/)) to detect these errors at compile-time and receive more meaningful error messages.

Comment: Extremely helpful! Thanks Again